# Use Pug (jade) as front end templates with express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, pug

I have an express app that loads my pug (jade) templates to do server side rendering. There are a few points in my site where I want to render a view client side. For example, most of a page loads server side with the proper pug (jade) template, but then I make an ajax call to my API that returns JSON. Then I want to take the JSON and load in a template based on the results. Rather than use another templating language like Vue.js, I would like to use Pug (jade) on the front end. This would allow me to reuse some code and also pass in things like moment.js etc.

I found this SO question / answer but it seems like this converts all the jade templates. [How to render precompiled Jade (Pug) templates in a Node.js Express app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183126/how-to-render-precompiled-jade-pug-templates-in-a-node-js-express-app)

How can I set up gulp (or something) to create front end templates for api calls that I can use in express?

Comment: Pug is a server side templating language.  I would just use JavaScript and bind the data to the view.  I suppose your AJAX calls could return static HTML generated via Pug, but I'm not sure I would want to go down that road.

Comment: Yes, Pug is server side, but I know there is a way to use gulp to precompile the views as js templates and then inject them into the app. Just not totally sure how